# Duplicate NSNotificationCenter observer when segueing to subclassed custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, nsnotification

I have a custom `UIViewController`, called `BoardViewController`, and I have subclassed this to create `GameBoardViewController`. I added an NSNotificationCenter observer in `viewDidLoad` of `BoardViewController`. When I segue from another view controller to `GameBoardViewController` it seems this observer is duplicated somehow. Because now, whenever I cause that particular notification to be posted, the method called from the observer is called twice. I have tested making `GameBoardViewController` the initial view controller in the storyboard and there are no issues. It only happens when I segue to it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

BoardViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gameBoardTileWasTapped:) name:@"gameBoardTileWasTapped" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(log:) name:nil object:nil];
}
```

GameBoardViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Can you show the viewDidLoad method of the BoardViewController and GameBoardViewController classes?

Comment: @yoninja As you can see in the code I added it is pretty straight forward. Maybe I am not understanding something basic about segues but it doesn't seem like `gameBoardTileWasTapped:` would get called twice from one observer. Thanks